# Create relationship between two lookup columns in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint List 'TeamValues' that defines values that should appear in another list.

TeamValues List:

```
Title    Team    Sub-Team
1        A       Blue
2        A       Green
3        B       Yellow
4        C       Silver
5        C       Gold
```

I have a list that users can edit and in this list I want to lookup 'TeamValues' list and create a dropdown list for users to select a value from the Team column. This needs to be unique so in this case the values that should appear are: A,B,C

Once they select a value I need a second column to populate a drop down list that users can select E.g. If they select Team: A, then the second drop down should show: Blue, Green as the options.

How can I do this using Sharepoint? I don't have any code access and only have the sharepoint GUI to work with.

Is this possible?

I have created a lookup choice column Team that looks at my TeamValues List however this is showing all values e.g. A,A,B,C,C. I have created a lookup choice column for the subteam that also shows every value. I dont know how to link these together or get a relationship between the two choice drop downs/ remove duplicate values. I tried the following option: 'the Enforce unique values is not displayed.' which did not work

No code applicable

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that but I think there is no OOB functionality to show distinct values of lookup column and to do this kind of relation without any code. I also did some research just to be sure but I could not find anything like that.

If You would consider some code You can always use javascript jsLink technology to achieve this. It's not that hard. It's a JS file that You can add to some lib on sharepoint site and then You can add this JS to webpart manually without any deploy or other. After that with javascript You can overwrite the default behavior of any control/column and do this kind of relation or show only distinct values.